# Optimizing for data import in Neo4j using py2neo

Tags: python, database, graph, csv, data-visualization

Here is my code for importing from a .csv to a neo4j graph using py2neo and cypher statements. I've noticed that it slows down significantly the bigger the graph gets. It takes several seconds just to parse ~10,000 lines. I'm curious to see if there are any glaring mistakes or improvements to be made.

Before doing any of the import, I created indexes for every node and property, based off of [this blog](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/).

The machine I'm working on is windows 7 with 65gb RAM, so it's certainly fast enough to handle a large graph. The upload of a 20 million line csv took weeks, so there has to be something that can be improved on.

I am currently stuck with using windows, I can't switch over to Linux. I also can't use Jexp's batch importer unfortunately.

```
import csv
import sys
import os
from py2neo import neo4j,node, rel, cypher
import time

def main():

    f = "C:file_path/file.csv"            

    graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")                        

    with open(f, 'r+') as in_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter = ',')
        next(reader, None)  # skip headers      
        batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)                           

        try:
           i = 0
           j = 0
            for row in reader:    
                if row:
                    if (i == 10000):
                        print j, "processed"
                        i = 0
                    i += 1
                    j += 1
                    character = strip(row[0])
                    first_name = strip(row[1])
                    last_name = strip(row[2])
                    actor = strip(row[3])
                    character_birth = strip(row[4])
                    character_death = strip(row[5])
                    allegiance = strip(row[6])
                    house = strip(row[7])
                    territory = strip(row[8])
                    region = strip(row[9])

                    query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db,
                    """CYPHER 2.0 
                       merge (character:Character {Character: {a}, First_Name:{b}, Last_Name:{c}, Actor:{d}, Birth:{e}, Death:{f}})
                       merge (house:House{House:{g}, Allegiance:{h}})
                       merge (territory:Territory {Territory: {i}})
                       merge (region:Region {Region: {j}})
                       merge (character)-[:Of_House{House:{k}}]-(house)-[:Is_From]->(territory)-[:Is_In]->(region)
                       """)
                    result = query.execute(a = character, b = first_name, c = last_name, d = actor, e = character_birth, f = character_death, g = house, h = allegiance, i = territory, j = region, k = house)

    except Exception as e:
        print e, row, reader.line_num #print the line number to fix any data errors in file     

def strip(string): return''.join([c if 0 < ord(c) < 128 else ' ' for c in string]) #removes non utf-8 chars from string within cell

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start=time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time() - start
    print "Time to complete:", end
```

Comment: Rather than doing the `query.execute()` once per row, is it possible to batch those queries and perform them later? I worked on a project which utilized rabbitmq and batching query execs gave us quite a nice speed boost - rather than doing 30 million network calls, we only did 3000 network calls using a 10k batch size EDIT: Seems it is possible http://py2neo.org/2.0/batch.html

Comment: I definitely thought of that. I'm just not entirely sure how to do that. would that be a substitution of `query.append()` for `query.execute()` and move the execute statement inside the `i == 10000` loop?

Comment: @jsanc623 It works great! thanks for the pointer, I'll post my code here soon, this a huge performance boost.

Comment: Certainly! Sorry I didn't see the earlier comment about how best to do it

Comment: Adding a bit more to this - you may want to profile your code with [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the updated solution with batching. I found that the request times out of the batch size is much larger than 1000, unfortunately and I'm not sure what causes that:

```
import csv
from py2neo import Graph
import time

def main():

    f = "C:file_path/file.csv" 
    graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")                            
    with open(f, 'r+') as in_file:

        reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None)        
        batch = graph.cypher.begin()                           

        try:
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            for row in reader:    
                if row:
                    character = strip(row[0])
                    first_name = strip(row[1])
                    last_name = strip(row[2])
                    actor = strip(row[3])
                    character_birth = strip(row[4])
                    character_death = strip(row[5])
                    allegiance = strip(row[6])
                    house = strip(row[7])
                    territory = strip(row[8])
                    region = strip(row[9])
                    query = """
                        merge (character:Character {Character: {a}, First_Name:{b}, Last_Name:{c}, Actor:{d}, Birth:{e}, Death:{f}})
                        merge (house:House{House:{g}, Allegiance:{h}})
                        merge (territory:Territory {Territory: {i}})
                        merge (region:Region {Region: {j}})
                        merge (character)-[:Of_House{House:{k}}]-(house)-[:Is_From]->(territory)-[:Is_In]->(region)
                    """
                    batch.append(query, {"a":character, "b": first_name, "c": last_name, "d":actor, "e":character_birth, "f":character_death, "g":house, "h": allegiance, "i":territory, "j":region, "k":house})
                    i += 1
                    j += 1
                batch.process()

                if (i == 1000): #submits a batch every 1000 lines read
                    batch.commit()
                    print j, "lines processed"
                    i = 0                
                    batch = graph.cypher.begin()
            else: batch.commit() #submits remainder of lines read                       
            print j, "lines processed"     

        except Exception as e:
            print e, row, reader.line_num

def strip(string): return''.join([c if 0 < ord(c) < 128 else ' ' for c in string]) #removes non utf-8 chars from string within cell

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time() - start
    print "Time to complete:", end
```